# What could be the reason for window.open behaving differently in IE?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, authentication, browser, get

We have two different Internet Explorer 11 browsers (different Windows and possiblty different architecture as well) that behave differently when I do `window.open(basepath + relativeurl)`.

In one IE we are seeing a single network request to `basepath + relativeurl` which is as expected.

However in another IE we can see that a request goes as expected to `basepath + relativeurl` as expected, however another request goes to `basepath`.

Any reasons why it could happen? I still need to get the exact version details, but this is the what is happening. Is there any reason why this could behave so? We came to know of this because our session expires if you sent a request again to `baseurl` so basically the whole application is getting expired.

I read something related to IE on Windows 7 64 bit if you open another tab, it opens a new **process** etc. You can also read here [subject-ie11-is-losing-cookie-information-and-thus-becoming-detached-from-a-web-application-session](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/810700/subject-ie11-is-losing-cookie-information-and-thus-becoming-detached-from-a-web-application-session)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently disabling "Content Advisor" in IE made everything normal.